# Join multiple rows of one table on one record (Codeigniter 3)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to build query which returns product with all images not only with one image.

This is my model for fetching products

```
function get_latest($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('products_pictures', 'products_pictures.id_product = products.id_product', 'left');
    $this->db->join('thumbs', 'thumbs.id_thumb = products_pictures.id_thumb', 'left');
    $this->db->join('images', 'images.id_image = thumbs.id_image', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by('date_c', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }
```

And this is output

```
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'id_product' => string '1000' (length=4)
      public 'name' => string 'Graham Corners' (length=14)
      public 'description' => string 'Et ea quaerat totam temporibus quis. Ut fugiat blanditiis vel corporis minus veniam. Consequatur corporis sint sed assumenda itaque ratione ipsum distinctio. Voluptate autem quo sunt rerum.' (length=189)
      public 'date_c' => string '2015-12-28 03:12:59' (length=19)
      public 'date_u' => null
      public 'id_category' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'id_user' => string '173' (length=3)
      public 'alias' => string 'graham-corners' (length=14)
      public 'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'id_product_thumb' => string '4996' (length=4)
      public 'id_thumb' => string '4996' (length=4)
      public 'thumb_path' => string 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?22290' (length=36)
      public 'id_image' => string '4996' (length=4)
      public 'image_path' => string 'http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?77489' (length=37)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'id_product' => string '1000' (length=4)
      public 'name' => string 'Graham Corners' (length=14)
      public 'description' => string 'Et ea quaerat totam temporibus quis. Ut fugiat blanditiis vel corporis minus veniam. Consequatur corporis sint sed assumenda itaque ratione ipsum distinctio. Voluptate autem quo sunt rerum.' (length=189)
      public 'date_c' => string '2015-12-28 03:12:59' (length=19)
      public 'date_u' => null
      public 'id_category' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'id_user' => string '173' (length=3)
      public 'alias' => string 'graham-corners' (length=14)
      public 'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'id_product_thumb' => string '4997' (length=4)
      public 'id_thumb' => string '4997' (length=4)
      public 'thumb_path' => string 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?87585' (length=36)
      public 'id_image' => string '4997' (length=4)
      public 'image_path' => string 'http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?76756' (length=37)
```

Cause i wan't to fetch all images of desired product i need to build a query which will output all product images under object product stored in some array or something
Desired output object should look similar to this

```
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'id_product' => string '1000' (length=4)
      public 'name' => string 'Graham Corners' (length=14)
      public 'description' => string 'Et ea quaerat totam temporibus quis. Ut fugiat blanditiis vel corporis minus veniam. Consequatur corporis sint sed assumenda itaque ratione ipsum distinctio. Voluptate autem quo sunt rerum.' (length=189)
      public 'date_c' => string '2015-12-28 03:12:59' (length=19)
      public 'date_u' => null
      public 'id_category' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'id_user' => string '173' (length=3)
      public 'alias' => string 'graham-corners' (length=14)
      public 'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'images' => array (
             [0] => stdClass Object
                 public 'id_thumb' => string '4998' (length=4)
                 public 'thumb_path'=> string 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?87585' (length=36)
                 public 'id_image' => string '4998' (length=4)
                 public 'image_path' => string 'http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?76756' (length=37)
             [1] => stdClass Object
                 public 'id_thumb' => string '4997' (length=4)
                 public 'thumb_path'=> string 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/?87585' (length=36)
                 public 'id_image' => string '4997' (length=4)
                 public 'image_path' => string 'http://lorempixel.com/1024/768/?76756' (length=37)
                 ........................
```

)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, you should combine only `id_thumb` as `id_thumbs` instead of all image data into `images` column. For example:

```
function get_latest($id)
{
    $this->db->select('products.*,product_pictures.*');
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(product_pictures.id_thumb) as id_thumbs',FALSE);
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('products_pictures', 'products_pictures.id_product = products.id_product', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by('date_c', 'DESC');
    $this->db->group_by('id_product');
    $this->db->limit($id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

And in your model make a function called as `get_image_data_by_id_thumb` as below:

```
function get_image_data_by_id_thumb($id_thumb='')
{
    if($id_thumb=='')
    {
        return false;
    }
    $this->db->where('id_thumb', $id_thumb);
    $this->db->join('images', 'images.id_image = thumbs.id_image', 'left');
    $sql = $this->db->get('thumb');
    $obj = $sql->row();
    if($obj)
    {
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
0 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'id_product' => string '1000' (length=4)
      public 'name' => string 'Graham Corners' (length=14)
      public 'description' => string 'Et ea quaerat totam temporibus quis. Ut fugiat blanditiis vel corporis minus veniam. Consequatur corporis sint sed assumenda itaque ratione ipsum distinctio. Voluptate autem quo sunt rerum.' (length=189)
      public 'date_c' => string '2015-12-28 03:12:59' (length=19)
      public 'date_u' => null
      public 'id_category' => string '7' (length=1)
      public 'id_user' => string '173' (length=3)
      public 'alias' => string 'graham-corners' (length=14)
      public 'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'id_thumbs' => '4998,4997,...'
```

Then you can fetch back by get image data by `id_thumb` using explode method:

```
$arr_id_thumbs = explode(",",$id_thumbs);
foreach($arr_id_thumbs as $row)
{
    $obj_image_data = $this->model_name->get_image_data_by_id_thumb($id_thumb);
    $thumb_path = $obj_image_data->thumb_path;  
    $image_path = $obj_image_data->image_path;
    .......................
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thx, i see your point. I will try code later today and let you know if its working.